# Why are the results different when multiplying OpenCV Mats?

Tags: opencv, mat

Here is a 4x4 transformMatrix Mat.

```
1.000, 0.000, -0.004, 0.784,
-0.000, 1.000, 0.001, -0.205,
0.004, -0.001, 1.000, -1.435,
0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000
```

Here is a 3-dimension vector

```
507.347,359.172,229.584
```

I performed the OpenCV Mat multiplication operation as follows

```
double data[] = { 507.347, 359.172, 229.584, 1 };

cv::Mat s(4, 1, CV_64F, data);
cv::Mat d = transformMatrix * s;
```

The output result is as follows, but it differs from the value calculated using a calculator.

OpenCV Mat Multiply `result = matrix * (507.347,359.172,229.584) = (507.394,359.158,229.605)`

Calculation `result = 507.213, 359.197, 230.538`

Why is the result different? Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Not sure about python, might rows and cols be switched? Can you try to change a single value in the matrix strongly and check in which row the result changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code (C++):

```
cv::Matx<double,4,4> M =
{
    1.000, 0.000, -0.004, 0.784,
    -0.000, 1.000, 0.001, -0.205,
    0.004, -0.001, 1.000, -1.435,
    0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000
};

double data[] = { 507.347, 359.172, 229.584, 1 };
cv::Mat s(4, 1, CV_64F, data);

auto Result = M * s;
std::cout << Result;
```

But, output becomes:

```
[507.212664;
 359.196584;
 229.819216;
 1]
```

not reproduce your result.

Perhaps, value of matrix you see is too low accuracy ?